# Construction of a K(pi_1)- space?

Tags: homotopy-theory

I was advised to post my question here. A  colleague suggested a proof of a fact which I have hard time to believe. Since I am not a topologist by training I wonder if this can be true in such a generality.

Consider any finite CW-complex structure on the -dimensional sphere $^$.  Let $$ be $^$ with all strata of codimension at least 2 removed, i.e. we keep just  and (−1)-dimensional strata of the complex under consideration.

Claim. K is contractible to a graph (the dual graph of the preserved strata). Thus it is a $K(\pi_1, 1)$- space where $\pi_1$ is a free group.

The claim is trivially true for d=2, but looks suspicious for higher d. Also if it is true then it might work for more general CW-complexes as well.

Best regards, Boris Shapiro/Stockholm University/

Comment: What do you mean more precisely ? For instance for $d=2$ if you take the standard cell-structure with one $2$-cell and one $0$-cell, how do you un-collapse the boundary of the $2$-cell ?

Comment: Well, in this case you remove the point. The remaining part in the 2-disk which is contractible to a point. $\pi_1$ is trivial. In general, in 2 dimensions, you remove a bunch of points (at least one). The remaining punched disc is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles.

Comment: Oh ok so just literally remove. Sorry for my question, I thought you meant something more sophisticated.